# Rebasing when existing commit hashes have changed

Tags: git

i'm trying to understand more about a git issue our team recently had. We have several layers of branches:

```
-> Master
   |-> Feature Branch
        |-> Individual developer branches
```

Small groups of developers work off a feature branch and we have several different feature branches going at once.

When one is merged with Master, feature branch owners will **rebase** their feature branches. Every so often they have merge conflicts with any work that's been merged to the feature branch from individual developers.

Fixing the merge conflict often changes the commit hash during rebase.

When an individual developer then does a rebase of the feature branch into their development branch, there are technically two commit hashes for the item that was corrected:

- The old commit hash (pre-rebase/merge-conflicts) still remains on the developer branch
- The new commit hash (post-rebase) now exists on the feature branch.

When this developer attempts to compare against the feature branch, the old commit is counted as a new work and "dirties" the pull request.

I can easily "workaround" this by having them create a new branch from the latest feature branch, and cherry-pick their work. This discards the old commit hashes, but this isn't efficient.

Is there any way to change our practice or rebase differently so that we can exclude "changed" commit hashes in developer branches?

Comment: You mention a pull request, what are you using for those?  Github?  Could you expand on what you mean by "dirties the pull request"?

Comment: We're using github enterprise, but that's unrelated to the problem. A comparison of the developers branch and the feature branch would show a list of commits to be merged that are already there - it's just that git doesn't recognize the commit hash anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR version: Have everybody use `git pull --rebase`.

---

If I understand you correctly, you have this situation.

```
A - B - C [m]
     \
      D - E - F [f]
           \
            G - H - I [d]
```

m for master, f for feature branch and d for dev branches.  You want to be able to rebase f onto m and also rebase d onto the new f.

```
                     G1 - H1 - I1 [d]
                     /
          D1 - E1 - F1 [f]
         /
A - B - C [m]
     \
      D - E - F
           \
            G - H - I
```

The answer is to have everybody `git pull --rebase` which is equivalent to a `git fetch` plus a `git rebase`.  Here's how it would work.  This is what the repositories look like after there's been work pushed to master (commit C).

```
origin
A - B - C [m]
     \
      D - E - F [f]
           \
            G - H - I [d]

feature branch maintainer
A - B [m][o/m]
     \
      D - E - F [f][o/f]
           \
            G - H - I [o/d]

dev branch maintainer
A - B [m][o/m]
     \
      D - E - F [o/f]
           \
            G - H - I [d][o/d]
```

Feature branch maintainer decides its time to update, so they `git pull --rebase origin master`.  This does a `git fetch origin` plus a `git rebase origin/master`.  Resulting in this.

```
feature branch maintainer
             D1 - E1 - F1 [f]
            /
A - B [m]- C [o/m]
     \
      D - E - F [o/f]
           \
            G - H - I [o/d]
```

Then they `git push origin` (I believe they will need to force) and this is the result.

```
origin
             D1 - E1 - F1 [f]
            /
A - B - C [m]
     \
      D - E
           \
            G - H - I [d]

feature branch maintainer
             D1 - E1 - F1 [f][o/f]
            /
A - B [m]- C [o/m]
     \
      D - E
           \
            G - H - I [o/d]

dev branch maintainer
A - B [m][o/m]
     \
      D - E - F [o/f]
           \
            G - H - I [d][o/d]
```

Now the dev branch maintainer wants to update, blissfully unaware that anything has happened to the feature branch.  They `git pull --rebase` which is equivalent to `git fetch origin` and `git rebase origin/feature`.  After the fetch it looks like this.

```
dev branch maintainer
             D1 - E1 - F1 [o/f]
            /
A - B [m]- C[o/m]
     \
      D - E
           \
            G - H - I [d][o/d]
```

And then the `git rebase origin/feature`.

```
dev branch maintainer
                         G1 - H1 - I1 [d]
                        /
             D1 - E1 - F1 [o/f]
            /
A - B [m]- C[o/m]
     \
      D - E
           \
            G - H - I [o/d]
```

And they can push that, probably with a `--force`.

You'll note that the dev branch is on F1, not E1 as it originally was.  If you want to maintain that you'll have to rebase specifically onto E1.

---

If Git can't figure out that D and E are not really part of the dev branch, you might wind up with this.

```
dev branch maintainer
                         D2 - E2 - G1 - H1 - I1 [d]
                        /
             D1 - E1 - F1 [o/f]
            /
A - B [m]- C[o/m]
     \
      D - E
           \
            G - H - I [o/d]
```

Git should be able to figure this out using "patch ids" which are like commit ids, but they only check the content and none of the rest.  If it can't, try updating Git and see if that helps.  If it still can't do it, then you are in what the git-rebase docs calls "the hard case".  You'll have to spell out to Git which commits you want to rebase with `--onto`.  Fortunately, the reflog contains the previous location of the feature branch as f@{1} and you can use that for reference.

```
git rebase --onto f f@{1}
```

That says to rebase the current branch (d) onto f, but only rebase from d to f@{1} (which is where f used to be).

---

I have `git pull --rebase` aliased to `git repull`.  I do this almost exclusively, it's fairly safe and generally the right thing.  You can configure it as the default with `git config --global pull.rebase true`.

For further information, see [Recovering From An Upstream Rebase in the `git-rebase` docs](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the core issue. We're already using `git fetch [remote]` and `get rebase [remote/branchname]`. When git rebases, it needs to identify which commits are "new work" and are not already present on the "upstream" branch you're pulling changes from.  Because the commit hashes have changed for a commit that is truly already on both , git thinks it's a new commit and attempts to "re-apply" those changes. Obviously, merge conflicts abound.

Comment: @helion3 Git should be able to do this with patch IDs, which are like commit IDs but only relate to the content change.  What I described is "the easy case" in the git-rebase docs.  You're describing "the hard case".  What version of Git are you using?  See "The Perils Of Rebasing" and "Rebase When You Rebase" in the [Rebasing section of *Pro Git*](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: @helion3 I have updated the answer to explain how to deal with "the hard case".

Comment: So I gather `git pull --rebase` is still doing different work that `git fetch [remote]` and `git rebase [remote/branch]` is not? `git pull --rebase` is being described (by you, and elsewhere) as what seems like an alias for the two commands, but if it's "the easy way" and somehow compares the patch-ids while a normal rebase doesn't?

Comment: Right now everyone is on fairly recent versions of git, within the past year at least. When I first looked at a problem branch this morning, I saw a few commits that did exist on the feature branch, but their commit hash had changed. Doing a `git fetch upstream` and then `git rebase upstream/feature-branch` acted as if the commits with "old" hashes were still new work, so it tried to re-apply them, and threw merge conflicts galore.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how a patch-id would be the same if the commit has been modified when the feature branch was rebased (to account for any conflicts). The patch-id the developer branch has would still be different than what the feature branch *now* has

Comment: @helion3 I can't help much more without seeing the details of your repository.  I'm available on codementor.io and HackHands if you want to consult.

Comment: Ok so I've made two branches from the "bad" branch. With `git fetch upstream/git rebase upstream/the-feature-branch`, it throws merge conflicts because it thinks the old hashed-commits are new work. Yet with `git pull --rebase upstream the-feature-branch`, it properly updates the base and applies the *actual* recent commit. There's something different between those two commands, one's not just an alias for the other. It works, but I want to find out why.

Comment: @helion3 Interesting!  Sounds like a new question.

Comment: I've already posted that as a new question, so here's hoping. I see no info in the docs as to why this is the case.